# Xamarin Installer ends prematurely when attempting to install on a Windows Server 2012 build server

Tags: xamarin, installation, xamarin.android, windows-server-2012

I am attempting to install Xamarin Android SDK by running the installer Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.0.4.4.msi on a Windows Server 2012 build server.

Below are the options I select:

[image: options selected on Xamarin Installer]

And the end result is this message:

[image: error message shown]

Which says:

> Xamarin setup wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your
> system has not been modified.

Has anyone encountered this error and managed to find a solution to be able to install the Xamarin Android SDK?

Comment: Did you find a fix in the past two months, @therobotichumanoid?

Comment: No I didn't find a fix. In the end devops installed an entire visual studio instance as a workaround.